# using telerik:RadGridView: Memory Leak

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a WPF app using `MVVM` design pattern.

as I am testing for memory growth, I have come across memory leak. I have been trying to fix for days without success. If possible someone can point out the issue.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--Service Header Editable Data-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
    </StackPanel>
    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grid"
                         IsReadOnly="{Binding IsServiceReadOnly}"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsModel.Collection}"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCharge, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         CellEditEnded="grid_CellEditEnded"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         ShowGroupPanel="False"
                         RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                         ShowColumnFooters="True"
                         CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
                         behav:GridFoucsBehav.GridFocusPosition="{Binding GridViewChargesFocColPos, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{lp:Lp UI:ServiceCode}"
                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding ServiceCode}">
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
                    <telerik:CountFunction Caption="c: " />
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CustomControl:MyControl 
                                      SelectedIDPath="ID"
                                      SelectedID="{Binding ServiceID}"
                                      StringToSearch="{Binding ServiceCode}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedService, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type v:MyView}}}"
                                      ExprQueryByString="{Binding DataContext.ServiceExprQueryByString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type v:MyView}}}">
                            <CustomControl:Lookup.DisplayMemberPaths>
                                <s:String>code</s:String>
                            </CustomControl:Lookup.DisplayMemberPaths>
                            <CustomControl:Lookup.ColumnHeaders>
                                <s:String>Code</s:String>
                                <s:String>Description</s:String>
                            </CustomControl:Lookup.ColumnHeaders>
                        </CustomControl:MyControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>

            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{lp:Lp UI:ReceiptView_NumberOfUnit}"
                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding NumberOfUnit}">
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <telerik:RadNumericUpDown Value="{Binding NumberOfUnit, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                  UpdateValueEvent="PropertyChanged"
                                                  Minimum="0" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{lp:Lp UI:Code}"
                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding Code, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{util:TwoWayBinding Code}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{lp:lp UI:Remarks}"
                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding Remarks,Mode=TwoWay}">
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Remarks, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
</Grid>
```

after opening few windows and closing them, the memory grows, and the objects are still hanged in the memory.

this is for my windows:

> MyWindow
>   System.Windows.DataTemplate-> MyApp.MyWindow->(System.Windows.Controls.Border,System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   [],System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher,...):    12 MB    (11.23%)  (3
>   objects,  852 bytes (0.00%))   Previous allocations (newest to
>   oldest):   11 MB    (11.22%),   7.4 MB    (7.19%),   7.4 MB
>   (7.19%),
>
> Referred to by:     12 MB    (11.23%)
>   from  System.Windows.DataTemplate System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   []->System.Windows.DataTemplate->(MyWindow,System.Collections.Specialized.HybridDictionary,System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher,...)
>
> Referring to:      668 kB    (0.64%)
>   to    Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadTabControl  MyWindow->Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadTabControl->(System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   [],System.Windows.Style,System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher,...)    93
>   kB    (0.09%)
>   to    MyApp.ItemsNavigator    MyApp.MyWindow->MyApp.ItemsNavigator->(System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel,System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher,Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadTabItem,...)
>       24 kB    (0.02%)
>   to    Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadContextMenu MyApp.MyWindow->Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadContextMenu->(System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate,System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   [],System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher,...)
>      2.8 kB    (0.00%) to   System.Windows.Controls.Border  MyApp.MyWindow->System.Windows.Controls.Border->(MyApp.MyWindow, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   [],System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher)
>      3.3 MB    (3.26%) to   MyApp.LocalizedValidationPanel  MyApp.MyWindow->MyApp.LocalizedValidationPanel->(System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter,System.Windows.Controls.Grid,System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher,...)
>      3.0 MB    (2.97%) to   MyApp.ExRadGridView MyApp.MyWindow ->MyApp.ExRadGridView->(System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   [],System.Windows.Style,System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher,...)
>      2.2 MB    (2.14%) to   Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView    MyApp.MyWindow->Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->(System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   [],System.Windows.Style,System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher,...)
>      1.1 MB    (1.06%) to   MyApp.MenuItem  MyApp.MyWindow->MyApp.MenuItem->(System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   [],System.Windows.Style,System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher,...)
>      1.1 MB    (1.04%) to   System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry []   MyApp.MyWindow->System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   []->(System.Collections.Hashtable,System.Uri,System.Windows.EventHandlersStore,...)

I got this. if it can be helpful

> Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.Entry
>   []->Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->(System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   [],System.Windows.Style,System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher,...):   12
>   MB    (100.00%)  (3 objects,  0.0 bytes (0.00%))
>
> Referred to by:     12 MB    (100.00%)
>   from  System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.Entry
>   []    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary->System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.Entry
>   []->(Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView)
>
> Referring to:       12 kB    (0.10%)
>   to    System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   []    Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   []->(MS.Utility.FrugalMap,System.Boolean,System.Windows.EventHandlersStore,...)
>      8.0 kB    (0.07%) to   Telerik.Windows.Data.DataItemCollection Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->Telerik.Windows.Data.DataItemCollection->(Telerik.Windows.Data.CompositeFilterDescriptorCollection,Telerik.Windows.Data.GroupDescriptorCollection,Telerik.Windows.Data.ObservableCollectionManagerCollection,...)
>      3.5 kB    (0.03%) to   System.Windows.Controls.Grid    Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->System.Windows.Controls.Grid->(System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection,System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry
>   [],System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher)
>      1.0 kB    (0.01%) to   Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Selection.GridViewItemSelectionHandler    Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Selection.GridViewItemSelectionHandler->(Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView,Telerik.Windows.Data.DataItemCollection,Telerik.Windows.Data.Selection.InternalSelectionItemsStorage)
>      912 bytes (0.01%)
>   to    Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Selection.SelectionDrag   Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Selection.SelectionDrag->(Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Scrolling.ScrollViewerCoordinator,Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Selection.DefaultMouseInfoProvider,Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView)
>      564 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewItemContainerGenerator    Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewItemContainerGenerator->(System.Collections.Generic.Queue,Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewItemContainerGenerator.ItemBlock,Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView)
>      504 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Selection.CellSelectionHandler    Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Selection.CellSelectionHandler->(Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Selection.CellInfoCollection,Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView)
>      504 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.DetailsProvider   Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.DetailsProvider->(System.Action,System.Func)
>      360 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    System.Globalization.CultureInfo    Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->System.Globalization.CultureInfo->(System.Globalization.TextInfo,System.String)
>      288 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    Telerik.Windows.Data.AggregateResultCollection  Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->Telerik.Windows.Data.AggregateResultCollection->(System.Collections.Generic.List)
>      288 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection  Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection->(System.Collections.Generic.List,System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection.SimpleMonitor)
>      240 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    System.Collections.Generic.HashSet   Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->System.Collections.Generic.HashSet->(System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer)
>      228 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    System.EventHandler  Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->System.EventHandler->(Behaviors.AlignGridViewCellBehav)
>      216 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.ItemDataCellPresenterHeightStorage    Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.ItemDataCellPresenterHeightStorage->(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary)
>      192 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Selection.CellAndRowSelectionDispatcher   Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Selection.CellAndRowSelectionDispatcher->(System.Func,Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.KeyboardModifiersProvider)
>      192 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection  Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection->(System.Collections.Generic.List)
>      180 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.ItemAttachedStorage   Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.ItemAttachedStorage->(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary)
>       72 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    System.Collections.Generic.List  Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->System.Collections.Generic.List->(System.Action
>   [])     36 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Selection.CompositeSelectionHandler   Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.Selection.CompositeSelectionHandler->(Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView)
>       36 bytes (0.00%)
>   to    Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.DefaultCellLocator    Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.DefaultCellLocator->(Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView)
>       12 MB    (99.74%)
>   to    Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumnCollectionInternal   Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadGridView->Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumnCollectionInternal->(System.Collections.Generic.List,System.Collections.Generic.List,System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection.SimpleMonitor,...)

as you noticed in the last details, it says `3 objects` after opening the window and closing for three times.
I have spent quite long time trying to figure out what is going on, but I couldn't. I worked on different screens with `RadGridView` and pretty much same controls and there is no problem. Did I miss out anything?

If you need further details, let me know

FYI: when RadGridView is commented out, there is no problem

**EDIT**
Adding another memory trace

> MS.Internal.ComponentModel.DependencyObjectPropertyDescriptor
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.Entry
>   []->MS.Internal.ComponentModel.DependencyObjectPropertyDescriptor->(System.Object,System.String,System.Windows.DependencyProperty,...):     12 MB    (100.00%)
>
> Referred to by:     12 MB    (100.00%) from
>
> Referring to:       12 MB    (100.00%)
>   to    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary  MS.Internal.ComponentModel.DependencyObjectPropertyDescriptor->System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary->(System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer,System.Int32
>   [])

I believe this is the problem, but I don't what cause property descriptor to be used.

Comment: Have your reported this to the developers? I believe you'll have better luck finding and answer there.

Comment: thank you @Oceans. I am the developer :). I found similar and different issues in other screens, all solved except this one. the problem is I don't know what the problem is :). I can see that there is property descriptor in there while tracing the memory [you can find it in the edit section in the question]. I have checked all the models used. All have got INotifyPropertyChanged and ObservableCollection are implemented, so I have run out of ideas to investigate.

Comment: I meant the developers of the telerik-framework

Answer (score 1):

It's been investigated for months and is related to WPF.

WPF has really complicated **Garbage Collector** which releases data after it is not needed anymore. The problem is, that it doesn't really know when exacly you won't need some components anymore.

```
 CellEditEnded="grid_CellEditEnded"
```

Are you unsubscribing this event, while closing your window? At some point it will be unsubscribed by Garbage Collector, but on the closing moment, it might still be in memory. And it's just an example. General advice from devs is "if you can unsubscribe event, when it's not needed anymore, do it", otherwise their existance in memory is prolonged.

My app still has memory leaks. Generally, I'm using RadTabControl, to present the data, but after closing tab, I still have unreleased memory (5-10 MB), which is finally released after time.

What I can recommend you to do, is checking [this article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/09/04/fighting-common-wpf-memory-leaks-with-dotmemory/) and using great memory analytics tool (Jet Brains one is awesome), as they can tell you what is taking the memory and not releasing it, referring to your code, functions and/or VisualTree of application. I can also recommend you to read this short article:

https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/learning-memory-management/WPF-silverlight-pitfalls

As a conclusion, I wanted to add that from my experience, you will not be able to prevent all of memory leaks.

Comment: thank you for that, but I had even tried that before posting the question. It didn't work.